# What is being said here instead of 逮捕状 (taihojou [arrest warrant]) (from Yakuza Lost Judgement)?

Tags: words, readings, slang, listening

During Yakuza Lost Judgement, detective Watanabe says the line "we even have a warrant", and the official japanese subtitles have the line written as "逮捕状も出てる". To my knowledge, 逮捕状 (arrest warrant) should be read as "taihojou", and yet that's clearly not what is said at all.

See the clip here: https://files.catbox.moe/0w5lnp.mp4

Official Japanese subtitles:
[image: official Japanese subtitles]

To me, it sounds like he's saying "fuda" (meaning slip of paper). Is this common slang? If so, I'd expect at least some furigana above 逮捕状 to indicate the alternative reading. Else, is this just an error?

Comment: Maybe pedantic but the game is just 'Lost Judgment'. While it is part of the Like A Dragon series, it doesn't bear the name in its title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's ふだ (札 in kanji).

> #### [令状](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BB%A4%E7%8A%B6)
>
> 司法警察職員の隠語では、令状を総称して、また逮捕状の意味で「フダ」（札）とも呼ぶ。

I think this is called ふだ because of its association with [*ofuda*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ofuda).

I don't know if this is a mistake or intentional. This is not a term everyone knows, so replacing it for the sake of clarity is at least understandable. We often see slang and sensitive words replaced with common words in transcriptions of interviews with ordinary people, but it is rare to see the same thing done in official subtitles of games.